# Mysterious behavoiur in bit fields

Tags: c

I have the bit fields like below

```
union
{
    unsigned int REG;

    struct
    {
        unsigned char toggle : 1;
    } flag;

    struct
    {
        unsigned char field : 3;
        unsigned char count : 3;
    } fields;
} bitfield;
```

When I toggle the bit `bitfield.flag.toggle = !bitfield.flag.toggle` every time it is affecting `bitfield.fields.field` i.e when `bitfield.flag.toggle` is zero `bitfield.fields.field` is also zero and vice versa. Why this is happening, this will not happen when there is only one `struct` like this

```
union
{
    unsigned int REG;

    struct
    {
        unsigned char toggle : 1;
        unsigned char field : 3;
        unsigned char count : 3;
    } flag;
} bitfield;
```

Comment: `union` means that all members share the same memory location. change to `struct` if you don't want that behaviour?

Comment: This is the intended behavior. The second and third union members are using the same bits (and as such altering the bits in one member changes the other members too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A union is a special data type available in C that allows to store different data types in the same memory location. In your case, toggle and field are using the same bytes. If you don't want this behaviour, you better avoid to use union.

Answer (score 5):

This is the behavior of the union. `REG`, `flag` and `fields` stored in the same memory location which size is the biggest one of them all. If you overwrite one the other ones are owerwritten too. If you would set `REG` for example to `0xffffffff`, so all 1s binary, then `flag` and `fields` should also have full 1s in their binary values.